# Port forwarding with traefik and docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, http-status-code-404, traefik, portforwarding

I would like to serve a docker-compose service through traefik with port-forwarding. I had many tries and the best I could achieve from now is described below:

First I create two networks:

```sh
docker network create frontend  # To expose traefik
docker network create backend   # To bind backend services
```

The traefik configuration is about (development, dashboard enabled at `:8080`):

```yaml
version: "3.6"

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api"
      - "--api.dashboard"
      - "--api.insecure"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      # Service entrypoint:
      - "--entrypoints.lora-server.address=:8090"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=frontend"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=traefik"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8090:8090"

networks:
  frontend:
    external: true
  backend:
    external: true
```

The backend service is described here (a fork from [ChripStack](https://github.com/brocaar/chirpstack-docker) but it could be anything else):

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  # [...]
  chirpstack-application-server:
    image: chirpstack/chirpstack-application-server:3
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/chirpstack-application-server:/etc/chirpstack-application-server
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=backend"
      - "traefik.http.routers.chirpstack.entrypoints=lora-server"
      - "traefik.http.routers.chirpstack.rule=Host(`{host:}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.chirpstack.service=chirpstack-application-server@docker"
      - "traefik.http.services.chirpstack-application-server.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
# [...]
networks:
  backend:
    external: true
```

The service also natively run on `:8080` and I would like to access it on `:8090` through traefik.

When I run both applications, traefik registers the new service and does not complain (no errors, no warning, the flow seems complete at least from the dashboard interface).

```
time="2020-07-30T11:47:47Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Pipelining serviceName=chirpstack-application-server@docker entryPointName=lora-server routerName=chirpstack@docker middlewareName=pipelining
time="2020-07-30T11:47:47Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=lora-server routerName=chirpstack@docker serviceName=chirpstack-application-server@docker
time="2020-07-30T11:47:47Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://192.168.112.9:8080" entryPointName=lora-server routerName=chirpstack@docker serviceName=chirpstack-application-server@docker serverName=0
time="2020-07-30T11:47:47Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware chirpstack-application-server@docker" middlewareName=tracing entryPointName=lora-server routerName=chirpstack@docker middlewareType=TracingForwarder
```

[image]
[image]

But I could not access the service, I am geting 404 errors when I try to connect `http://host:8090`.

To my understanding, it seems traefik does not know how it should complete the flow between the two networks: `http://frontend:8090 -> http://backend:8080` (because I haven't referenced it anywhere).

What should I change in my configuration to make it work? How can I specify to traefik that it must route the HTTP traffic from `frontend:8090` to `backend:8080`? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traefik listens on some port, that's the only thing defined with `entrypoints`. You don't specify network for this incoming requests, because it's unrelated. `traefik.docker.network` is only used for routing **after** Traefik handles the incoming requests.

So the correct flow is not `http://frontend:8090 -> http://backend:8080`, but `http://host:8090 -> http://backend:8080`.

I think your configuration is correct. The only thing which seems to be odd is usage of `Host` rule. Maybe try to change it to something like this:

```
"traefik.http.routers.chirpstack.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
```